# Simulating the process of obtaining share size

Tags: c#, exception, file-io

I have written some code to simulate the process of gaining share drive sizes. The drives come from a text file. The problem is that the paths get to a stage which exceed the 250? charachter limit. Is there anyway this can be avoided.

I found something on-line which suggested placing @"\?\" before the filepath but am unsurue if it will work for definate and if i am using it correctly or not?

Thanks

```
        void getSizes_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            String val = "";
            float megabytes = ((float)e.Result / 1024f) / 1024f;
            if (megabytes > 10240) //greater than 10 gig
                val = (megabytes / 1024.0).ToString() + "GB";
            else
                val = megabytes + "MB";
            textBox1.Text += val;
            textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
        }

        void getSizes_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            String s = (String)e.Argument;
            String path = Path.GetFullPath(s);
            float bytes = (float)GetDirectorySize((String)e.Argument);
            e.Result = bytes;
        }

        protected static float GetDirectorySize(string folder)
        {
            float folderSize = 0.0f;
            try
            {
                //Checks if the path is valid or not
                if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
                    return folderSize;
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(folder))
                        {
                            String path = @"\\?\" + file;
                            if (File.Exists(path))
                            {
                                FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(path);
                                folderSize += finfo.Length;
                            }
                        }

                        foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(folder))
                            folderSize += GetDirectorySize(dir);
                    }
                    catch (NotSupportedException e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Unable to calculate folder size: {0}", e.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to calculate folder size: {0}", e.Message);
            }
            return folderSize;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to only provide relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath about information on path lengths and the `\\?\` prefix.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe(v=vs.71).aspx for more information about `@""` strings.

It should give you more information on the subject, at least enough to ask a more specific question.